# Send email without env variables in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Laravel version - 8

**What Am I trying to do?**

Sending email without env variable.

**Error Details**

```
Connection could not be established with host mailhog :stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
```

Am i missing anything?

**Code**

```
config('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp');
config('MAIL_USERNAME', "email username");
config('MAIL_HOST', "smtp.gmail.com");
config('MAIL_PASSWORD', "password");
config('MAIL_PORT', "port");
config('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', "tls");

$invitedUser = new Admin();
$invitedUser->email = "recipient email address";
$invitedUser->notify(new TestingNotification());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
config(['mail.mailers.smtp.host' => "host"]);
config(['mail.mailers.smtp.encryption' => "tls"]);
config(['mail.mailers.smtp.username' => "username"]);
config(['mail.mailers.smtp.password' => "password"]);
config(['mail.mailers.smtp.port' => "port"]);
config(['mail.mailers.smtp.from' => "from"]);


$invitedUser = new Admin();
$invitedUser->email = "recipient";
$invitedUser->notify(new TestingNotification());
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems like there's something wrong with your configuration. The error mentions `mailhog` as a **host**, but that probably is not what you wanted.

Maybe you wrote things like `config('MAIL_HOST', "smtp.gmail.com");` as pseudo code, but usually you'd set this up in your `mail.php` config file. For example:

```
'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),`.
            ...
        ]
]
```